# Margin-bottom not working on table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to put margins on the bottom of a table to separate it from the content below it (another table). I tried creating a class:

```
.seg_table {
margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

And then applied it to the table like this:

```
<table class="seg_table">
<tr>
<td>Some Content Here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm new to working with tables so I assume I am making some simple mistake here. Normally, I would use a div to space out the content but there are forms involved and that would invalidate my code.

Comment: Yeah, seems like it should work right -

Comment: Does the content comming after the table (as you say it's another table) have a margin-top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait, I got it. Sorry - my reset style sheet was interfering. Thanks, anyhow.

Answer (score -3):

> .seg_table {
>   margin-bottom: 25px;
>   }

I think its better to use

table.seg_table{
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

Comment: Just curious - why is it better to target that way?

Comment: It only depends on how specific you have to be on your cascade. There are many people who actually advice AGAINST selectors like table.class instead of just .class (for performance and DRY reasons).